# How to extract as csv file multiple rows with single id containing all the attributes that belong to that one specific id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner in Python and do not have much experience with it. My scenario is as follows:
I have data that contains many records with different ids. Each id has multiple records (rows containing the same id) but different attributes. I extracted and grouped each attribute for each id, but I need to have each id with the attributes that belong to that id. Thank you very much!
My goal is to achieve something like this below:

Example of a dataset:

```
    id, F, V
    ---------
    1, a, 50
    1, b, 40
    1, c, 20
    1, d, 10
    2, a, 15
    2, d, 25
    2, e, 35
    3, a, 45
    3, b, 55
    3, d, 65

    Desired Outcome:

    id, a,  b,  c,  d,  e
    -------------------------
    1, 50, 40,  20,  10, N/A
    2, 15, N/A, N/A, 25, 35
    3, 45, 55,  N/A, 65, N/A
```

[Example of a dataset and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPGzj.png)

[Screenshots of Jypter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLxGi.png)

Here is some of my code in Jypter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
hdata = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
hdata

df = hdata.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'procedure', 'value'])
df = hdata.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'procedure'])

mrn = df['id'].unique()
procedure = df['procedure'].unique()
for i in mrn:
    result1 = df.loc[df['id'].isin([i])]
    for j in procedure:
        result2 = df.loc[df['procedure'].isin([j])]
        result2.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\results2.csv', mode = 'a', index = False)
        print(result2)
    print('NEW PATIENT')
print('END!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''id, F, V
    1, a, 50
    1, b, 40
    1, c, 20
    1, d, 10
    2, a, 15
    2, d, 25
    2, e, 35
    3, a, 45
    3, b, 55
    3, d, 65'''), sep=', ', engine='python')

df.pivot(index='id', columns='F', values='V')
```

Ouput

```
F   a   b   c   d   e
id                  
1   50.0    40.0    20.0    10.0    NaN
2   15.0    NaN NaN 25.0    35.0
3   45.0    55.0    NaN 65.0    NaN
```

Comment: How can I insert a .csv file which I have with three columns (id, F, V) instead of a string?

Comment: Not sure i understand. Isn't this your df  with the three columns you want? df = hdata.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'procedure', 'value'])

Comment: Yes, it is. I just named it shorty as letters (id, F, V). Those names [id, procedure, value] are the real column names in the .csv file which I want to read from.

Comment: I solved it using: df = pd.read_csv(io.FileIO('dataset.csv'), sep=',', engine='python'). Thank you very much @Jonathan Leon.

Comment: How can I now search all columns and rows, and keep just the records which are not NaN?

Comment: Glad it worked. There are examples on stack overflow that show how to remove NaN from data frames under different scenarios.

Comment: Okay. I will try to search for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole solution for my problem with the output saved into a .csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.FileIO('dataset.csv'), sep=',', engine='python')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'procedure', 'value'])
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'procedure'])
results = df.pivot(index='id', columns='procedure', values='value')
results.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\results.csv')
```

Thanks!

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhIQK.png)